# border-bottom in panel-heading not displaying full width when window shrink

Tags: html, css

How to make the border-bottom of the panel-heading display full width when the window shrink and the horizontal axis appear below the panel-body? The border is normally displayed when the window maximized, but only display the width same as the window when the window shrink.
Here is the code:

```
<section class="panel">
<header class="panel-heading" style="display:block;"></header>
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"></table>
</div>
</section>

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #535351;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 52px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-width: 1130px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  display: table;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by Minimize?

Comment: Request you to place your CSS Code for people to solve your problem

Comment: Border bottoms of block elements normally have the full width, so can you make a demo page where it goes wrong? There is probably some other CSS involved, perhaps a @media query that messes with things.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="panel">
<header class="panel-heading" style="display:block;"></header>
</section>
<section class="panel">
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"></table>
</div>
</section>
```

This code solved my problem. Just separate the heading into a new section.

Comment: Do you also know _why_ it solved your problem? What was the issue? When I put this in a jsfiddle, I don't see any difference with the original.